# How do you make everyone's gamertags in Minecraft invisible?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am making a "Murder Mystery" mansion in Minecraft (Windows 10 Edition, not Java), and I want to turn off the gamertags. Does anybody know how to turn them off, or make them invisible?

Answer (score 0):

## This is not yet possible in Minecraft Bedrock-Edition

There are a few work-a-rounds I could find,

1. Everyone setting their gamertags to nothing - Works only once
2. Giving all players invisibility, which hides the gamertag, and wearing armour to show position - Hinders visibility, particle effects.

Comment: Well for particle effects, you could add the "true" to the "hideparticles" at the end of the command. Like "/effect @a invisiblity 1000 1 true"

Comment: @darthvader1925 - Unsure what the necropost is for. This is 2 years old...

Comment: oh... oops. Sorry bout that. I have a bad habit of not checking post dates

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings, scroll down to video, scroll down till you see in game names and turn it off.

Comment: Is this a server-side setting? If not, it wouldn't apply to each player.